# controller with the same name in a different area

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

The return is ambiguos controller with same name
I Tried some code, as routeAttribute [Route] and [Area], but without success.
I'm using Asp.net Core MVC - C#

[structured](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63NBH.png)

```
case 1:
redirection = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "first" }); ;
break;
case 2:
redirection = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "second" });
break;
```

My Route:

```
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Login}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
              name: "areas",
              template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
           );

            //routes.MapRoute("areaRoute", "{area:exists}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            //routes.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        });

[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AllowAnonymous]
    [Area("first")]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        [Route("first")]

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public IActionResult Logout()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Logout", "Login");
        }

    }
```

Comment: Is the namespace added correctly in the `RoutConfig.cs` ?

Comment: Have you tried to use `[Area("")]` attribute on each controller?

Comment: yes, i tryed...

Comment: what is your route config?

Answer (score 1):

Merge your route definitions to be in a single `UseMvc` call, and always have your default route last, the order matters.

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "areas",
    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Admin}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
  );

  routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Login}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
  });
});
```

Try that and see if it fixes the routes for you. I don't see anything super obvious problems with your code other than that, but I would avoiding calling your route "first" if the area is called "first". I feel like that'll just confuse things.

Might want to clean up your 'default' values for your controllers though.

I know what you're trying for is possible, I've done it many times in my code. If it still doesn't work let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
case 1:
    redirection = Area.first.Controllers.HomeController.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "first" }); ;
    break;
case 2:
    redirection = Area.second.Controllers.HomeController.RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "second" });
    break;
```

Comment: not working,  tried but he does not even show the method RedirectToAction Controllers.HomeController.XXX